# ChunkedEncodingError ao fazer requests no python

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests, urllib

Boa tarde pessoal. Estou tendo um problema com requests para raspagem de dados.

A função principal é a que segue:

```
def raspa_dados(lista_de_links, ministerio):

    links = []
    autores = []
    chamadas = []
    datas = []
    ementas = []
    for i in lista_de_links:
        time.sleep(0.01)
        html = trata_html(requests.get(i).text)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        orgao = soup.findAll('span', class_="orgao-dou-data")[0].get_text()
        chamada = soup.findAll('p', class_="identifica")[0].get_text()
        data = soup.findAll('span', class_="publicado-dou-data")[0].get_text()
        ementa = soup.findAll('p', class_="ementa")
        if ministerio in orgao:
            if chamada.split()[0] in tipos or chamada.split()[0] in primeira_maiuscula(tipos):
                autores.append(orgao)
                chamadas.append(chamada)
                datas.append(data)
                links.append(i)
                if len(ementa) >= 1:
                  ementas.append(ementa[0].get_text())
                else:
                  ementas.append(None)
    return links, autores, chamadas, datas, ementas
```

Recentemente eu adicionei esta linha do `time.sleep(0.01)` na esperança de solucionar o problema.

Sigo recebendo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
ConnectionResetError                      Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py in _error_catcher(self)
    361             try:
--> 362                 yield
    363 

18 frames

ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ProtocolError                             Traceback (most recent call last)

ProtocolError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ChunkedEncodingError                      Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/models.py in generate()
    752                         yield chunk
    753                 except ProtocolError as e:
--> 754                     raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
    755                 except DecodeError as e:
    756                     raise ContentDecodingError(e)

ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Alguém sabe me dizer o que está errado?

Comment: Eu testaria algumas coisas para identificar melhor o problema. Se você passar apenas um valor na lista de links, seu webscrapper funciona? Se ele funcionar passando apenas um valor, faz ele printar qual link ele está da lista, e descobre se é sempre o mesmo link que está causando o erro. Se não for sempre o mesmo link que tá causando erro, eu colocaria um teu except no código para tentar mais de uma vez fazer a conexão com site e se falhar 2-3 vezes ele simplesmente continuar com o resto e me avisar no final qual site ele não conseguiu.

Comment: com um valor apenas dá o mesmo erro

Comment: Então, o erro pode estar na função trata_html ou no site que você está tentando fazer o scrap. [Stackoverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/what-does-connection-reset-by-peer-mean) explicando o que o connection reset by peer significa.